Windows 11 C# tessertOcR 5.3 hide leptonica 1.8.3 console output and Add border to multi page tiff
Windows 11 C# tessertOcR 5.3 hide leptonica 1.8.3 console output and  Add white border  to multi page tiff to fix some messages. Do not see any method to set border.
Tried console output to null and try setting debug variable

By using "Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null)", you can effectively hide any console output generated by your application by redirecting it to null. If that doesn't work as expected, you could try using the "FreeConsole" function. This function can be useful if you want to completely disable the console window associated with your application.
For adding a white border to a multi-page TIFF image, you could utilize the"System.Drawing" namespace. This namespace provides a variety of classes and methods for working with images in .NET applications. You can explore the functionality provided by "System.Drawing" to manipulate the TIFF image and add the desired white border. If you encounter any issues, please feel free to ask for further assistance.Here is a code example you could refer to .
for (int i = 0; i < image.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); i++)
             {
              image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                 using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
                 using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                 {
                     // Add white border
                     using (var pen = new Pen(Color.White, 10)) // Adjust border thickness as needed
                     {
                      graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, bitmap.Width - 1, bitmap.Height - 1);
                     }
                     // Save the modified page
                  bitmap.Save($"output_page_{i}.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
                 }
             }

